# Why doesn't "go to definition" work when using mixed CommonJS and ECMAScript module imports?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my application I am going back from using ES6 modules to only use CommonJS modules.

In ES6 modules I can easily import functions from certain files and VS Code allows me to Ctrl+click them to jump into definition of that function.

With CommonJS modules that isn't working anymore. I am only able to jump into the required module (start of that certain file) and not into that specific function I clicked on.

Is there any setting, plugin, or workaround?

**Minimal reproducible example:**

functionsToImport.js

```js
import * as Consts from "./constants.js";
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');
    
exports.exportTest = function()
{
    console.log("exportTest called");
}
```

app.js

```js
const MyFunctions = require('./functionsToImport.js');
MyFunctions.exportTest();
```

start app:

```dos
$ node app.js
```

When I try to Crtl+Click on exportTest-Function in app.js VS Code won't let me go to function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example VS Code can't deal with ES6 module imports in files where CommonJS exports are provided.
This means that VS Code cannot establish the link between CommonJS export and its import at another position.

Replacing all ES6 modules with CommonJS syntax solves the problem and VS Code is able to "go to function" by Crtl+Click again.